# offline indexing over an ordered set of strings for wildcard searching

Tags: search, data-structures, indexing, wildcard, trie

I want to implement a wildcard search feature to a large but finite set of strings
here is what I want: ? for 1 char, * for 0 or more chars.
What I've already known:

1. use trie, or variants of trie can solve the problem pretty good,
   WITHOUT * matching
2. although use a reversed trie do solve * problem, by coupling match
   results of both tries, yet I want the strings to be "alphabetically"
   ordered, and memory used by intersection calculating could be
   serious.

similar problems have found at http://www.codechef.com/JAN10/problems/L2, but I can't find somebody explains their codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using regex library. Take a look at this which I have implemented. [Regular Expression library in C++](http://code.google.com/p/regex/)

Comment: Hi ,thanks. I have seen a few articles about regex, and as you explaned in your project, it converts search keys rather than targets to be matched. so I'll still have to roll the DFA on every word in my target string sets, which could be costy.